# Does a car need the same distance to brake from 100 to 70 as from 70 to 0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, friction, work

In [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3D7XYQExt0) it is claimed that a car can basically brake equivalent to constant energy per distance.

Is this true - both in theory in practice? And if so, why?

It's clear that air resistance is ignored, and probably rightfully (since it's about approximate results), but won't the brakes behave vastly differently regarding their energy absorption behaviour at different speeds?

Edit to clarify, based on the first responses - I'm not curious about how Numberphiles reached their results, I understand that. I want to understand why the underlying assumptions make sense. My intuition is that brake behaviour depends a whole lot on speed.

Comment: If you have not yet learned about the work-energy theorem then that's the place to starts. Or the place to go back to if you don't see the relevance.

Comment: Basic newton mechanics are clear to me, I'd think. The question really is more about what happens in car brakes at various speeds, regarding applied force and absorbed energy depending on speed.

Comment: Well you have to make some assumptions. But the basic relationship comes from the kinetic energy of the car.

Comment: @Desiato I don't understand what do you mean in your edit. If the braking (deceleration) is different between the cars, then what's the meaning of your question, of course, they will be different.

Comment: Brake behavior depends on temperature, not speed.  If you haven't overheated them, they will respond very similarly at a range of speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, at the limit of braking capability[1], the brakes aren't stopping the car, they're just holding the wheels in place, so that the wheels can stop the car. The acceleration to stop the car is provided by the frictional force, so braking distance is determined by starting velocity and coefficient of friction. Work is force times distance, so distance will be work (energy) divided by force. Friction is affected only by normal force and coefficient of friction, not speed. There would be a slight effect that if a car brakes enough, the rubber will start to melt, increasing coefficient of friction, but that's not usually a significant factor.

[1] I added this qualification because for light braking, the wheels continue to turn, and the brakes slow the wheels down. In that case, the brakes will be absorbing energy. But if you're doing maximum braking, then wheels lock up (the car skids), and the limiting factor becomes the friction between the wheels and the ground. This is complicated by the fact that locking the wheels/skidding is dangerous, and so most have ABS (Anti-lock Braking System) that keeps you from locking the wheels. But the limit is still mostly friction, as the brakes slow the wheels with friction, and the amount that you can brake without going into a skid depends on friction.

Comment: Oh. So tire friction is the limiting factor, not actual energy absorption capabilities of the brakes. After you wrote this, it makes a ton of sense.

Comment: @Desiato In the extreme case, but I've added a qualification.

Comment: Right, but the question is about the extreme case (the video discusses an emergency braking situation).  And your argument alleviates my concerns regarding complicated behvaiour of brakes at various speeds, since the sheer fact that ABS exists shows that tire friction is what limits braking, not brake energy absorption.

Answer (score 0):

*Numberphile* assumes that the same braking force is used over the same distance. So the same amount of work is done by the brakes, and the same amount of kinetic energy is converted into heat energy.

The fast car reaches the barrier first, so there is less time for the heat generated at the braking surface to permeate into the brake pads. This means that the braking surface is slightly hotter at the same distance. Hotter brakes don't perform so well. But the deterioration in performance is very small, because brakes are designed to withstand high temperatures in excess of $500^{\circ}C$. There would only be a noticeable difference from repeated hard braking over a long journey.

Braking performance is not *vastly different* at different speeds.

Answer (score -1):

Netwonian mechanics. Doesn't matter what's the kinetic energy is. If the deceleration is same, then yes, the car-1 going at `100mph` would be at `71.41428mph`, while car-2 goes from `70mph` to `0mph`.

```
|v^2 - u^2| = 2 * a * s

v = Final velocity
u = Initial velocity
a = acceleration/deceleration
s = distance covered
```

For car-1 going from 100mph to 70mph, it will cover distance s in `5100/2a`, whereas car-2 would cover distance `4900/2a`.
If car-1 wants to cover same `4900/2a` as the distance, then `u` would be `71.414mph`, which is nothing but `sqrt(5100)`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You are only repeating the calculation made in the video.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the car brakes the same, its kinetic energy is given by

$KE = \dfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ where

$KE$ = kinetic energy of car
m = mass of car
v = velocity of car

Difference in kinetic energy is due to difference in velocity and mass of car stays the same. Thus:

$\Delta KE_{\text{100 to 70}} = \dfrac{1}{2}m (100^2 - 70^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}m(5100) = 2,550m$

$\Delta KE_{\text{70 to 0}} = \dfrac{1}{2}m (70^2 - 0^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}m(4900) = 2,450m$

$\therefore \Delta KE_{\text{100 to 70}} \approx \Delta KE_{\text{70 to 0}}$

Comment: This does not answer the question. You are only repeating the  calculation made in the video.